# Dropdown box isn't staying open after I click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I have a dropdown box that is part of a plugin, I haven't coded it myself. The problem is that when I click it, it disappears as soon as I stop clicking the mouse. Is there any way I can get it to toggle on and off when I click, rather than having to hold down the mouse?

http://le1dev.co.uk/eclaimed/2/directory/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser? Seems fine in Chrome...

Comment: Works properly in Firefox.

Comment: @8odoros I'm using Chrome on Mac. Odd because client also stated the same issue.